# How do I switch the git repository Xcode 4 uses in a workspace?

Tags: xcode, git

I started out being able to commit to my git repository in the base folder of my project while using a workspace.

Then I added another library to my project and didn't notice that it had it's own git repository in it's root folder. I proceeded to make changes to that library and committed those changes through Xcode but after I did that it seems the Xcode switched the git repository it was using for all files diffs in my project to that library's git repository.

How to I switch back to my original project's repository? I tried deleting the library's git repository but Xcode still tries to commit to that project's repository.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to correct the git repository directory path using Xcode's Organizer window.